# Shabbat and Mishkan - Order of items

Tags: shabbat, parshanut-torah-comment, mishkan-tabernacle, parashat-ki-tisa, vayakhel

I noticed an interesting "anomaly".

From the beginning of parshat *Terumah* through *Tetzaveh* and into the beginning of *Ki Tissa*, G-d details numerous laws of the *mishkan* (Tabernacle). At the end, G-d mentions Shabbat.

When Moshe assembles the people at the beginning of *Vayakhel*, he mentions Shabbat first, and then this is followed by the *mishkan* assembly.

Why when G-d is talking is Shabbat last, but when Moshe is talking, Shabbat is first?

Comment: @JoelK Purim must have hit me too hard, this year. Another dupe of my own question!

Comment: I saw there was a rashi referenced for this question (in my chumash) but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

This question is addressed by [Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) in the beginning of Parshas Vayakhel:

> הנה הקדים משה בזה הסיפור זכרון שמירת השבת לעשית המשכן וכל אשר בו אע"פ
>   שהיה מאוחר במה שקדם מדברי השם יתע' אלא לפי שהכוונה בזה הוא להודיע שאין
>   מלאכת המשכן דוחה שבת והקדימו משה מפני זה
>
> In this narrative Moshe mentioned keeping Shabbat prior to
>   [mentioning] the construction of the mishkan and everything in it,
>   even though [the mishkan was mentioned] later in the words of Hashem
>   (may He be exalted) that preceded this, because the intent of this was
>   to make known that the work of the mishkan does not override Shabbat;
>   for this reason Moshe [mentioned Shabbat] first.

[Ramban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) gives the same reason for Shabbat preceding the mishkan here, but he doesn't specifically relate it to the fact that the order is reversed from earlier:

> והקדים השבת לאמר כי ששת ימים תעשה מלאכת אלה הדברים ולא ביום השביעי
>   שהוא קודש לה' ומכאן שאין מלאכת המשכן דוחה שבת ולא ממדרש אך כמו שפרשתי
>   בסדר כי תשא